# How do I use VBA to vlookup a value from another worksheet, while passing variables into the vlookup function

Tags: excel, vba, variables, vlookup

I am attempting to create a robust formula to vlookup a student's enrollment status for the current term (C, N, D, G, S)

I need to do this because the term will vary and therefore the distance between the Student ID column and the current term will vary based on when the VBA is run.

I want to produce the answer on the "Sit Out and Drop Reason Report" worksheet in column L2, because I have further work to do on this sheet once the vlookup answer is produced.

I thought my formula would work, but it keeps only producing the IfError option, so I am going wrong somewhere.

The current term is identified in a cell on the "Roster" worksheet, and identified by the CurrentTermSelect variable in my VBA script, which corresponds with a term column farther to the right in the "Roster" Worksheet.

Using this, I was able to get the range of cells for the vlookup that I wanted for the second input of the vlookup, using the StudentIDtoTermRange variable, and the number of cells from the beginning of the range to the end for the third input of the vlookup with the ColumnCount variable.

These images are of relevant worksheets for the code:
[Roster worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uO4Kd.png)
[Sit Out and Drop Reason Report worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMWvC.png)

Below is my code, the final formula in the code is what is not executing correctly:

```
Sub A_SRPSitOutandDropDataCheck()
    
    'finds D on SRP drop report and changes status for current term to D
    
    
    Sheets("Sit Out and Drop Reason Report").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long
    
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sit Out and Drop Reason Report")
    
    lastRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Set rng = ws.Range("A1:A" & lastRow)
    
    ' filter and delete all but header row
    With rng
        .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="<>*Alvernia University*"
        .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    End With
    
    ' turn off the filters
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    
    
    Sheets("Roster").Select
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    
    Dim CurrentTermSelect2 As Integer
    Dim CurrentTermSelect As Integer
    Dim CurrentTermSelectCell As String
    Dim FirstEnrollmentTerm As Integer
    Dim CurrentTermColumn As Integer
    Dim CurrentTermCell As String
    Dim CurrentTermCellLocation As String
    Dim CurrentTermFullColumn As String
    Dim StudentIDColumn As Integer
    Dim StudentIDColumnCellLocation As String
    Dim StudentIDFullColumn As String
    
    'creates variables to denote the content of the current term selection cell
    CurrentTermSelect = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Choose Term here -->", Range("A1:O1"), 0) + 1 ' gives the cell location as 11
    CurrentTermSelectCell = Cells(1, CurrentTermSelect) 'executes to give the cell contents as Spring B 2023 from the Roster Section
    
    'Finds the start column of the Enrollment Section
    FirstEnrollmentTerm = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Status", Range("A2:Z2"), 0) 'gives the cell location as 15
    
    'Sets the range of cells to the above selection and on to the end of the roster
    Set r = Range(Cells(2, FirstEnrollmentTerm), Cells(2, FirstEnrollmentTerm).End(xlToRight))
    
    'Creates variables to denote the current term in the Enrollment section of the Roster
    CurrentTermColumn = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(CurrentTermSelectCell, Intersect(r(1).EntireRow, r).Offset(-1, 0), 0) 'gives the cell location as 58
    'finds the current term in the enrollment section,adds the number of columns from the first section to get to the first status column, and subtracts one to get the number of columns to the term
    CurrentTermCell = Cells(1, CurrentTermColumn + FirstEnrollmentTerm - 1) 'executes to give the cell contents as Spring B 2023 from the Enrollments Section
    CurrentTermCellLocation = Cells(1, CurrentTermColumn + FirstEnrollmentTerm - 1).Address 'executes to give the cell location as $BT$1
    CurrentTermFullColumn = Split(CurrentTermCellLocation, "$")(1) 'executes to give the column as BT
    
    'Creates variables to denote the student ID in the Roster section
    StudentIDColumn = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Student ID", Range("A2:O2"), 0) 'gives the cell location as 4
    StudentIDColumnCellLocation = Cells(1, StudentIDColumn).Address 'executes to give the cell location as $D$1
    StudentIDFullColumn = Split(StudentIDColumnCellLocation, "$")(1) 'executes to give the column as D
    
    'Sets range from Student Id column to Current Term column
    Dim StudentIDtoTermRange2 As String
    Dim StudentIDtoTermRange As Range
    StudentIDtoTermRange2 = (StudentIDFullColumn & ":" & CurrentTermFullColumn)
    Set StudentIDtoTermRange = Worksheets("Roster").Range(StudentIDtoTermRange2)
    
    ColumnCount = StudentIDtoTermRange.Columns.Count 'executes to count columns between student ID column and current term as 69
    
    Sheets("Sit Out and Drop Reason Report").Select
    numberofrows = Range("D2").End(xlDown).Row
    Sheets("Sit Out and Drop Reason Report").Select
    Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(numberofrows, 12)).Select
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(numberofrows, 12)), , xlYes).Name = _
                                                                                                       "SRPData"
    Range("SRPData[#All]").Select
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("SRPData").TableStyle = "TableStyleLight11"
    
    Range("SRPData[[#Headers],[Column1]]").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "FLV Status"
    Range("L2").Select
    
    ActiveCell.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError(Application.VLookup(F2, StudentIDtoTermRange, ColumnCount, False), "Not in FLV")
    
End Sub
```

Comment: The `Application.VLookup` at the end of your sub, have you experimented with it to determine how it works?  Are you sure that "F2" shouldn't be passed as a range, for example?  As written, F2 should be a variable, but I think you want to refer to the contents of the cell F2.

Comment: And that seems to be exactly the issue.  when I updated F2 to Cells(2,6) it produces exactly what I need.  THANK YOU!